# How to make slide deck in R based on a list?

Tags: r, slideshow, ioslides

I have some moderate experience in R. I'm trying to make flashcard slides for remote learning. I need to display the slides on my screen for my student to read, and flip through them quickly.

I have a list of about 4,000 words, broken down into different categories. I want to be able to filter on the category, and build a slide deck that has one word on each slide.

The pie-in-the-sky goal would be a Shiny app, with a drop-down to select category, then a check-box selection to select which words to include in the slide deck, then produce an html slide deck.

Below is a sample of the word list I'm using:

Word Category | word  | index

---

Short a CVC  | ban | 1

Short a CVC  | bat | 1

Short a CVC  | can | 1

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. I would suggest the following [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to maximize your chances of having some feedback. If you can put your data in a table form. A `data.frame` or a `data.table`, then the filtering part is rather straightforward. If you are in a hurry you might consider [anki](https://apps.ankiweb.net/).

Comment: Could you specify in what form are your data exactly? Is it `csv`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest for a first pass you should make an R Markdown document with `Slidy` or some other HTML presentation format output.  Just include one or two slides in it, and play with it until the format looks right.

Then write an R function that outputs the header and as many slides as required to a file, then calls `rmarkdown::render()` on that file.  Your R function can take as input all the characteristics like `Category` that you will eventually put in the Slidy app.

To get you started, here's a two-slide `Slidy` presentation:

```
---
output: slidy_presentation
---
##

<div style="font-size:300%;position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;transform: translate(-50%,-50%)">
ban
</div>
##

<div style="font-size:300%;position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;transform: translate(-50%,-50%)">
bat
</div>
```

The first 3 lines are the header; after that, slides start with the `##` marker.  See the `Slidy` documentation if you want to customize it.

Once you have this working from your R function, you can write a Shiny app that offers choices in menus then calls that function.

Edited to add:  for various reasons, it turns out that `xaringan` isn't well suited to this, so I've switched everything to `Slidy`.  The function below uses Slidy.

```
makeSlideDeck <- function(words, outfile = "slides.html") {
  header <- '---
output: slidy_presentation
---'
  slide <- '##

<div style="font-size:300%;position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;transform: translate(-50%,-50%)">
WORD
</div>'

  lines <- character(length(words) + 1)
  lines[1] <- header
  for (i in seq_along(words))
    lines[i + 1] <- sub("WORD", words[i], slide, fixed = TRUE)
  filename <- paste0(tools::file_path_sans_ext(outfile), ".Rmd")
  writeLines(lines, filename)
  rmarkdown::render(filename)
}
```

Run it like this:

```
dat <- c("ban","bat","can")
makeSlideDeck(dat)
```

It will produce `slides.Rmd` and process that into `slides.html`, which will contain your slides.

Comment: That's exactly how I want it to look! Thanks. Now, if I have a list that is of ```n``` length, how can I make a slide deck contain ```n``` number of slides

Comment: As in:   ```dat <- c("ban","bat","can")```   then have each slide contain  ```dat[1]```, ```dat[2]```, etc.